# How to force an exception in JPA when executing a joinTransaction() or commit()?

Tags: unit-testing, exception, jakarta-ee, jpa

For testing database related code using JPA using an in-memory database such as HSQLDB:

How can I force an exception raised when executing `EntityManager.joinTransaction()` or `EntityManager.getTransaction().commit()`?

I'd like to force the exception without altering tables from the database (ex. deleting the table where the test would perform a `persist()`).

Answer (score 0):

Some ways,

- shutdown your database
- violate a foreign key or unique constraint

For joinTransaction() I'm not sure you could do much, as it just joins the JTA transaction.  It would throw an error if you were not in a JTA transaction, or potentially already in a transaction, or resource_local.